# vba outlook save attachments in csv format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba, csv

I'm trying to save a spreadsheet attachment in CSV format.

I can trigger the process when a spreadsheet attachment is found but I'm having a hard time combining that with a conversion script which takes two arguments.

> **saving an attachement**

```
Public Sub saveAttachToDiskcvs(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 

 ' --> Settings. change to suit
Const MASK = "Olus" ' Value to be found
Const SHEET = "sheet2" ' Sheet name or its index where to find
 ' <--

 ' Excel constants
Const xlValues = -4163, xlWhole = 1, xlPart = 2 

 ' Variables
Dim objExcel As Object, IsNew As Boolean, x As Object 
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
Dim saveFolder As String, sFileName As String, sPathName As String 
saveFolder = "C:\form" 

If Not TypeName(itm) = "MailItem" Then Exit Sub 
If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir saveFolder 

 ' Get/Create Excel object
On Error Resume Next 
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
If Err Then 
    Err.Clear 
    IsNew = True 
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
End If 
objExcel.FindFormat.Clear 

 ' Main
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments 
    sFileName = LCase(objAtt.FileName) 
    If sFileName Like "*.xls" Or sFileName Like "*.xls?" Then 
        sPathName = saveFolder & "\" & sFileName 
        objAtt.SaveAsFile sPathName 
        With objExcel.workbooks.Open(sPathName, ReadOnly:=True) 
            Set x = .sheets(SHEET).UsedRange.Find(MASK, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) 
            If x Is Nothing Then Kill sPathName Else Set x = Nothing 
            .Close False 
        End With 
    End If 
Next 

If IsNew Then objExcel.Quit 

End Sub
```

> **CSV format**

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the     
destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

the idea is *`If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xls")`* if **`.xls`** is found Then

convert **`.xls`** file in **`.csv`** and

save file in folder **`objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "" & objAtt.DisplayName`**

I tried so many times it never worked, the conversion script take two arguments Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"

Answer (score 1):

If your only want to save it as ***[CSV Format then use FileFormat:=xlCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709)***

---

Example

```
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    sFileName = LCase(objAtt.FileName)
    If sFileName Like "*.xls" Or sFileName Like "*.xls?" Then
        sPathName = saveFolder & "\" & sFileName
        objAtt.SaveAsFile sPathName

        CVSName = Split(objAtt.FileName, ".")(0)

        Debug.Print CVSName

        CVSName = saveFolder & "\" & CVSName

        Debug.Print CVSName

        With objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathName)
            .SaveAs FileName:=CVSName, _
                    FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                    CreateBackup:=False
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With

        Kill sPathName
        objExcel.Quit
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh!!! How much I hate it when people post code snippets, but do not provide the entire thing all cleaned up... :)

Anyway, thanks to your combined work I was able to complete my task in less than a day, so here you go Internet. FREE CODE.

Added:

1. I cleaned it up and I even added some logic to delete the first ten rows from the Excel sheet, because our data extract comes with HEADERS so now it is a CLEAN CSV file.
2. I added argument to use the LOCAL settings on the machine, so you can set LIST DELIMITER to anything you want in the CONTROL PANEL under REGIONAL SETTINGS. It kept saving COMMA delimited regardless of my system settings, so now this should respect my System Settings and use PIPE.
3. Finally, I am working with Office 2016 and I had to make sure the EXCEL 16 LIBRARY was added to references.

[VBA References in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pC24.png)

SIMPLY PERFECT!!!

```
Public Sub Convert_CSV(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

' Variables
Dim objExcel As Object, IsNew As Boolean
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String, sFileName As String, sPathName As String

' CONFGURE FOR YOUR DEPLOYMENT
saveFolder = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xls"

If Not TypeName(itm) = "MailItem" Then Exit Sub
If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir saveFolder

' Get/Create Excel object
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
    Err.Clear
    IsNew = True
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
objExcel.FindFormat.Clear

' Main
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
  sFileName = LCase(objAtt.FileName)
  If sFileName Like "*.xls" Or sFileName Like "*.xls?" Then
    sPathName = saveFolder & "\" & sFileName
    objAtt.SaveAsFile sPathName
    CVSName = Split(objAtt.FileName, ".")(0)
    CVSName = saveFolder & "\" & CVSName
    With objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathName)
      ' Delete first ten rows.
      For i = 1 To 10
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
      Next

      .SaveAs FileName:=CVSName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        Local:=True, _
        CreateBackup:=False
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With

    Kill sPathName
    objExcel.Quit
  End If
Next

If IsNew Then objExcel.Quit


Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objAtt = Nothing


End Sub
```